# Redirect Users to another website using GAS

Tags: html, google-apps-script, redirect, url-shortener

I have a website for url//link shortening, that uses Google Spreadsheets and Google App Scripts,

I have been trying to find a way to redirect the users when they type my link, but app scripts either tries to load the redirection URL in an iframe which gets rejected by most sites these days or I have to open up a new tab using `window.open(url, _blank);` which acts as a pop up that has to require permission from the user to open up the first time.

Now i'm aware that I can create an html button which will then redirect them, but thats a really slow and tedious process for a url shortener.

So if anybody is aware on how I can redirect the user automatically instead of making a click button or opening a new tab with popup please do share.

Here is the link to my website that shortens links and then redirects:

https://surl.jayeshrocks.com/

Heres the `doGet` function for the Code.gs script

```
function doGet(e) {
  var slug = e.queryString;
  if (slug == '') {
    var title = 'Dashboard | ' + serviceName;
    return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Dashboard').setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL).setTitle(title);
  } else {
    var notFound = false;
    var redirectsData = getRedirects();
    for (var i = 0; i < redirectsData.length; i++) {
      if (slug == redirectsData[i].slug) {
        var redirectURL = redirectsData[i].longURL;
        var html = "<body>Redirected! You can now close this tab.</body><script>window.open('" + redirectURL + "','_blank');</script>";
        return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Redirected!');
        break;
      } else {
        notFound = true;
      }
    }
    if (notFound) {
      var html = "<body>No redirections found! Redirected to Link Loom. You can now close this tab.</body><script>alert('No redirects found!');window.open('" + customDomain + "','_blank');</script>";
      return HtmlService.createHtmlOutput(html).setTitle('Error 404');
    }
  }
}
```

If you would like to check out my full script, here is the link:

https://script.google.com/d/1lAwOw4Os0bZI5Ze1orJd-Crjg_MkKt0WUavO87VCME07C6QdgN7kxxQQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: "but thats a really slow and tedious process for a url shortener." But you're using Google Sheets for this.

Comment: Yes because it's the one I found that I can easily integrate with GitHub Pages that will allow me to host it 24/7 without a MySQL server and running Apache on my pc. If you have suggestions on how I can host my website without a MySQL server and GitHub pages, feel free to share.

Comment: [Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/free) and [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/free/) have free tiers (so long as you stay under certain generous quotas) that seem like they could fit your use case. ([Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/) also has a free tier but I think it's missing bits you'd need.) Possibly [Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/cloud/free/), but it's not as clear if that would fit.

Comment: Unrelated, but it seems like you don't require any kind of authentication or authorization to create and use your links. This opens you up to an element that loves using such services to get safe-looking urls for definitely unsafe use.